# Looking for elegant way to assign ActiveRecord instance to two owners at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I have following models association structure in my rails app:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folders
  has_many :notes
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :folder
end
```

What i want is to make call

```
@folder.notes.create()
```

to assign the note to folder and folder owner at once.

In other words instead of

```
@folder = current_user.folders.first
...
@note = Note.new    
@folder.notes << @note
current_user.notes << @note
```

I want to just

```
@folder.notes.create()
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

---

Update

Or how can I override **create**, **new** and **<<** functions for notes in every Folder instance.

Comment: `@folder.notes.create(user: current_user)` is one way

Comment: Thanx @Sharagoz, but I want to avoid this explicit parameter as the folder already knows its user. Sorry for being so hypercritical

Comment: If the note and its folder always belongs to the same user then isnt the `belongs_to :user` association on `Note` completely redundant and can be removed?

Comment: I understand you @Sharagoz. But the problem is that a note can exist without any folder..

Comment: Ok, I see. If the folder is present will it always be the same user for note and folder? If that's the case you can create a callback in the model layer where the user association is copied from the folder when the folder is present.

Comment: Yes @Sharagoz, the user should always be the same for his folders and all his folder's notes. What callback exactly do you mean? And would I have access to the new note in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, thanks to @Sharagoz for pointing me in callback direction!

`after_add` callback does the trick.

Here is what I have changed:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notes, after_add: :add_to_user

  def add_to_user(note)
    if(self.user)
      self.user.notes << note
    end
  end
end
```